# C++ Array with typedefed elements

Tags: c++, arrays, types, double, typedef

Can typedefs which refer to the same type be mixed together in an array?

```
typedef double seconds;
typedef double meters;
```

Would I be able to make an array that can contain both seconds and meters?

```
double sec_met[2] = {variable_with_type_seconds, variable_with_type_meters};
```

The logical answer would be yes, since the typedefs are mere aliases for types, and hence the datatype would still be the same.

Comment: Way faster to just test with your favorite compiler.

Comment: This is also just sorta a question that's thrown out there, so people can come to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Longer answer: Yes since a `typedef` is an alias. :)